# The Hilbert space of Dirichlet Series, with square-summable coefficients is not an algebra

Tags: hilbert-spaces, dirichlet-series, hardy-spaces

Consider the Hilbert space of Dirichlet series
$$\mathcal{H}^2=\lbrace f(s)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{a_n}{n^s}:\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}|a_n|^2<\infty\rbrace,$$
with norm $\|f\|_2^2=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}|a_n|^2$. Why the Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}^2$ is not an algebra. That is, there exist an element $f\in\mathcal{H}^2$ and an element $g\in\mathcal{H}^2$ such that $fg\notin\mathcal{H}^2$.

If $f,g\in\mathcal{H}^2$, the Dirichlet series of $f$ has coefficients $a=\{a_n\}$ and the Dirichlet series of $g$ has coefficients $b=\{b_n\}$, then their product can be expressed by a Dirichlet series, with coefficients $c=\{c_n\}$, where $c=a*b$, the Dirichlet convolution of the sequences $a$ and $b$. In other words, $$c_n=a_n*b_n=\sum_{ij=n}a_i b_j.$$
By definition $a\in\ell_2$ and $b\in\ell_2$, where $\ell_2$ is the space of square-summable sequences. Is always  $c\in\ell_2$? If not can you provide a counterexample?

Comment: For some $p$ prime and $a \in (1/2,3/4)$,

$F(s) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty p^{-sk} (k+1)^{-a}$, $F(s)^2 = \sum_{k=0}^\infty p^{-sk} \sum_{m=0}^k (k-m+1)^{-a} (m+1)^{-a}$ where $\sum_{m=0}^k (k-m+1)^{-a} (m+1)^{-a}$ $ \ge (k+1) \inf_{m \le k} (k-m+1)^{-a} (m+1)^{-a}\approx (k+1)  (k^2/2)^{-a}$ which is not square summable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see an explicit example of $f, g\in \mathcal{H}^2$ such that $f\cdot g \notin \mathcal{H}^2$, but we can prove that such $f,g$ must exist.

Suppose to the contrary that for all $f,g \in \mathcal{H}^2$ their product $f\cdot g$ also belongs to $\mathcal{H}^2$. Then the product is a (commutative) bilinear map $\mu \colon\mathcal{H}^2 \times \mathcal{H}^2 \to \mathcal{H}^2$. Since convergence with respect to $\lVert\,\cdot\,\rVert_2$ implies pointwise convergence of the coefficients and $\mathcal{H}^2$ is a Banach space, the closed graph theorem asserts that $\mu$ is separately continuous. For, if for a fixed $g\in \mathcal{H}^2$ we have $\lVert f_k - f\rVert_2 \to 0$ and $\lVert f_k\cdot g - h\rVert_2 \to 0$, it follows that $h = f\cdot g$, since the coefficients of $f_k\cdot g$ converge to those of $f\cdot g$. But a separately continuous bilinear map on a product of Banach spaces is continuous by the Banach-Steinhaus theorem, so there is a $C\in (0,+\infty)$ with

$$\lVert f\cdot g\rVert_2 \leqslant C\cdot \lVert f\rVert_2\,\lVert g\rVert_2\,.\tag{$\ast$}$$

However, no such $C$ exists: For $\varepsilon > 0$, let

$$f_{\varepsilon}(s) = \sum_{k = 0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^{k(\varepsilon+s)}}\,,$$

so the coefficients are

$$a_n = \begin{cases} n^{-\varepsilon} &\text{if } n = 2^k\,, \\\; 0 &\text{if } n \text{ is not a power of } 2\,.\end{cases}$$

Then the coefficients $b_n$ of $f_{\varepsilon}\cdot f_{\varepsilon}$ are $0$ if $n$ is not a power of $2$, and

$$\sum_{m = 0}^k 2^{-m\varepsilon}\cdot 2^{-(k-m)\varepsilon} = (k+1)2^{-k\varepsilon}$$

for $n = 2^k$. We compute

$$\lVert f_{\varepsilon}\rVert_2^2 = \sum_{k = 0}^{\infty} 2^{-2k\varepsilon}  = \frac{1}{1 - 2^{-2\varepsilon}}$$

and

\begin{align}
\lVert f_{\varepsilon}^2\rVert_2^2
&= \sum_{k = 0}^{\infty} (k+1)^2\cdot 2^{-2k\varepsilon} \\
&= \sum_{k = 0}^{\infty} (k+2)(k+1) 2^{-2k\varepsilon} - \sum_{k = 0}^{\infty} (k+1)2^{-2k\varepsilon} \\
&= \frac{2}{(1 - 2^{-2\varepsilon})^3} - \frac{1}{(1 - 2^{-2\varepsilon})^2}\,,
\end{align}

so

$$\frac{\lVert f_{\varepsilon}^2\rVert_2^2}{\lVert f_{\varepsilon}\rVert_2^4} = \frac{2}{1-2^{-2\varepsilon}} - 1$$

tends to $+\infty$ as $\varepsilon \to 0$, contradicting $(\ast)$.